# plotted chart candlesticks are broken

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts, candlestick-chart

I am working in echarts candlestick. It works based on dynamic values. However, every candlestick looks broken:

[image: like this].

In the x-axis, I have dynamic time and the y-axis contains price. Also I tried with highchart, but it looks the same. My candle array value looks like this:

```
[
  1: 10716.0149
  2: 10732.0156
  3: 10716.0143
  4: 10732.014


 1. 10732.015
 2: 10733.019
 3: 10723.0146
 4: 10723.0149

 1: 10737.0118
 2: 10737.019
 3: 10735.0116
 4: 10735.0116
 ]
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

my code for chart : [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc4tbuw4/2/)

Comment: Your values are not well formatted. Are those the acutal values copied from code or dummy data? Do you mind reproducing this in a Jsfiddle so we can have a look at it ourselves?

Comment: this is my array values here my  code : https://jsfiddle.net/sc4tbuw4/2/

Comment: Your js fiddle does not work. Please fix it, so it does reproduce your error.

Comment: This API page explains how to format candlestick series data in **Highcharts:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.data

Here you can find a live working example of that type of series:http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick/

Comment: thanks i tried that too..... same as the above echarts result. it looks like broken. because i have larger values like 10732.015
10733.019..... let me know if you have any solution for this